# Using Netty with HTTP 2.0

Tags: java, http, netty, spdy

I would like to compare the performance of SPDY vs HTTP 2 (preferably a recent draft). I've googled a bit and found that scalantra has an extension for Netty 3.x (https://github.com/scalatra/netty-extension/find/master), however I'd prefer using a new version of Netty if possible.  Does someone know of a similar extension that works with Netty 4.x or 5.x?

Comment: None as far as I know.  I guess it might be a good candidate for this year's GSoC though.

Comment: I'd be happy to put together a pull request for Netty, unless you're aware of someone else already working on it.

Comment: HTTP2 support started in `master` and `4.1` branches of Netty, see https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/4.1/codec-http2